# How do I make a button seem like pressed and then unpressed from code naturally in c# for WP7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, button, pressed

I am trying to make buttons seem like pressed automatically so the user can then follow the buttons pressed but everytime I try it doesn't seem natural because the computer does it really fast all the changes!
Any ideas? I have to get a serious of buttons pressed that look like user pressed and then pass to unpressed again

Thanks a lot!!!!

Well I'm trying to make a game where you remember the buttons that were randomly selected by the computer and then you press them, so I need computer to act like if the user were touching them and then the user follows...

Comment: wat? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: Can you explain your problem in detail and with some context?

Comment: I Think he's trying to make an app that you'd chase the button presses or something (i.e. you have to press the button within 1 second of it being depressed)? Anyway, It would probably be best to just use some UserControl/image set where you swap between a pressed/unpressed state on a DispatcherTimer or something

Answer (score 1):

How about using a custom storyboard animation that takes the button to the pressed, and then unpressed state?